# How to use python bookmark function inside a .py script?

Tags: python, function

I am using python V 2.7 and trying to use the bookmark function to give a alias name to a directory however not sure how to call the function inside a .py script.

Below is the current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess

########################################
#The script showcases functions
########################################

def bookmark_func():
    response = raw_input("Please enter the directory name:")
    print("The input directory is",response)
    os.chdir(response)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print("Current working directory is:",cwd)
    response2 = raw_input("Please enter a bookmark variable")
    subprocess.call([bookmark, response2])
bookmark_func()
```

I have tried few ways however i am not sure how to incorporate python builtin functions in a .py script.

Comment: What do you mean "builtin functions"? You're already using one - `raw_input()`. Also what "few ways" did you try?

Comment: I am going through a PDF for python which mentions 

`"There are two ways to create bookmarks. Here is
the first way:
In [1]: cd /tmp
/tmp
In [2]: bookmark t
By typing in bookmark t while we’re in /tmp, a bookmark named t is created and pointing at /tmp."`

This works if i type bookmark in the directory i wish to alias from the console, essentially i can rename a directory like a symbolic link and move to the directory with the new name. My concern here is how do i call this function inside a script when i am reading the directory through users input. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: It's unclear to me how this `bookmark` command got on the PATH, but that has nothing to do with Python

Answer (score 0):

To make it run when you run the file (I guess that's what you are looking for) change the following 
`bookmark_func()` 
to

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
         bookmark_func()
```

This checks the calling points and makes it run.

Comment: I think the question is asking how to import this script's function into another